# Unable to read warning during boot stage through socat for a virtual serial port

Tags: linux, virtualbox, docker, serial-port, socat

I am trying to deploy Docker image(converted to vmdk - Sata controller - vdi created) on VirtualBox.

This is I am doing through automation, at this stage I have enabled serial port "host device" > "path/to/file" on the virtual machine so that I can use socat to read and enter against prompts during the deployment phase.

During the init phase, when the Virtual Machine comes up, the screen shows warning , which is never captured by socat, instead socat reveals the next step i.e. entering password and skip showcasing this warning(below).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlNwj.png)

After more troubleshooting, I found that socat delibrately puts/converts newline characters and add multiple ^M due to which I am assuming that this warning is getting skipped.

Is there way that I can either: 1. Make socat not to enter ^M unnecessarily. 2. Or disable this prompt ?

BTW socat command I am using is:

```
socat - /path/to/file,ignoreeof
```

Or could this be related to baudrate or other settings (btw i tried different rates but no luck as it socat fail to read virtual port if I specify baudrate)

Answer (score 0):

If `/path/to/file` is a named pipe, why not use `tee` to capture the output of the pipe, write it to a real file and monitor it at the same time on the terminal? As in `cat /path/to/file | tee /tmp/serial.log`.

If I understood you correctly, you don't need to enter anything until it asks for the password, and the warning will be displayed before that. You can then inspect `/tmp/serial.log` with `less` or a text editor, and read everything there is to read.